# jQuery modal height is too small

Tags: css, jquery-ui, height

I have a dialog that pops on `$(document).ready(function() {`, it blocks the whole page with `modal : true`.

```
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                hide: "explode",
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false
            });
        });
```

The problem is that when `$(document).ready(function() {` fires, all the images in the page may not be loaded.

It results in having the overlay's height smaller than the page actually is.

(ex :) You have a page with 2 images (height of 100px). When the `$(document).ready(function() {` fires, you have a height of 800px, then the overlay appears, with a height of 800px. after that, when the images had the time to load, you have a 1000px page... So if I scroll down, there is 200px at the bottom that is not blocked by the overlay.

---

What i'm trying to do is, when `$(window).load(function() {` will fire (so everything will be loaded), **refresh the height of the overlay, if the dialog had not been closed of course**.

I noticed that, once all of the images are loaded, if I zoom +/- or If I open Chrome's developer tool, it refreshes the overlay height.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this..

```
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            hide: "explode",
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false
        });
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
        $(window).resize();
    });
```

So I pop the dialog, then when the images are loaded, I just refresh the size..